# How to query column name with space using AWS S3 SQL syntax?

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I have the following csv file saved in an AWS S3 bucket:

```
Currency Pair,Spot,Date
AUDJPY,70.123,2019/12/12
SGDUSD,0.72,2019/12/12
CADUSD,0.75,2019/12/12
```

When I use the AWS s3 web interface and choose the "select from" header, the following syntax runs successfully:

```
select * from s3object s limit 2
```

But when I try to reference `Currency Pair` as below, I get the error **Invalid Ion literal at line 1**. I also get errors trying [Currency Pair], Currency\ Pair, and 'Currency Pair'

```
select * from s3object s where `Currency Pair` = 'AUDJPY'
```

How can I select from a table with a column name with a space? From searching, it seems like special characters apart from underscore are not allowed. Can I either reference columns by index or re-define the schema? I would like to run this in python using boto3.

Comment: Ideally, athena should not have allowed a space in the column name https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/tables-databases-columns-names.html

Comment: Try using the alias with double quotes. `Select * from s3object s  where s."Currency Pair" = 'AUDJPY'`. See if this reference helps: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html

Comment: Aha @SS_DBA - that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the alias with double quotes.

`Select * from s3object s where s."Currency Pair" = 'AUDJPY'.`

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference-select.html

Comment: I found also that one can use that sort of syntax to return a specific field in the input that has a space:
        ```Expression="SELECT s.\"Currency Pair\" FROM s3object s WHERE s."Currency Pair" = 'AUDJPY'```